# Searching Data in DynamoDb using HashKey, Sort Key and Global Secondary Indexes

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to search the data using HashKey(Id), SortKey(timestamp) and Global Secondary Indexes(requestId) but not getting proper result.

```
public List<EventLogEntity> getOndemandRequestDetails(String vin, String requestId) {
        LOGGER.debug("processing OndemandRequestDetails based on request id");
        PaginatedQueryList<EventLogEntity> paginatedResult = null;
        String id = vin + UNDERSCORE + GATEWAY_ON_DEMAND_REQUEST;

        Map<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<>();
        eav.put(":val1", new AttributeValue().withS(id));
        eav.put(":val2", new AttributeValue().withS(requestId));

        DynamoDBQueryExpression<EventLogEntity> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<>();
        queryExpression.withKeyConditionExpression("id = :val1").withFilterExpression("requestId = :val2")
                .withExpressionAttributeValues(eav).withConsistentRead(false);

        paginatedResult = dynamoDBMapper.query(EventLogEntity.class, queryExpression);
        return paginatedResult;
    }
```

What I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set the **index name** in the query expression.

If the index name is not set, you are querying the actual table rather than GSI.

```
queryExpression.withKeyConditionExpression("id = :val1").withFilterExpression("requestId = :val2")
                .withExpressionAttributeValues(eav).withConsistentRead(false)
                .withIndexName("YourGSIIndexName");
```